# ¿Como divido un string en caracteres con python?

Tags: python

Quiero dividir un string por caracteres algo así:

```
MyString="PaLaBrA"
```

y que devuelva algo así

```
MyString_1="P"
MyString_2="a"
MyString_3="L"
MyString_4="a"
MyString_5="B"
MyString_6="r"
MyString_7="a"
```

Comment: La verdad, es que es antinatural dividir un string de esa forma. El string en python de por sí ya es una lista de caracteres separados, puedes tomar cada uno de la siguiente forma: `MyString[0]`, `MyString[1]`... Como observación lo digo, si es por fin didáctico (sacado de un libro) este comentario no va.

Comment: Hola, como obtengo la cantidad de caracteres?

Comment: usando `len(MyString)` como con cualquier otra lista.

Comment: hola, tengo otra pregunta, como inserto una variable dentro del nombre de una variable? Osea algo asi "Var_{var_a}="Contenido"

Comment: Eso sería una lista o un diccionario, revisa [esta página](https://tutorialpython.com/listas-en-python/), creo que hace falta que investigues un poco de información por tu cuenta

Comment: hola, pero no entiendo como hacerlo `Var_{Numero_Variable}="var_content"`

Comment: Yo lo que no entiendo es por que usar una tecnica innecesariamente compleja como crear multiples variables teniendo las cadenas la capacidad de acceder a cada uno de sus caracteres usando slicing (por ejemplo var[0])

Comment: porque la variable va a ser un input del usuario y necesito dividirlo para cada uno de los caracteres convertirlos a binario y escribirlo en un archivo

Comment: Aun así podrías hacerlo con un bucle for iterando directamente en la cadena y convirtiendo en binario caracter por caracter. Me parece raro que lo necesites. Primero no es buena practica. Y segundo los bucles y las listas suelen hacer innecesario lo que buscas. Es más, yo nunca lo necesité hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma común de hacer eso es construir un código como string y luego llamar a `exec()` para que lo ejecute.

```
MyString="PaLaBrA"

i = 0
try:
    while True:
        letra = MyString[i]
        nombre_variable = "MyString_" + str(i+1)
        asignacion = nombre_variable + "='" + letra + "'"
        exec(asignacion)
        i += 1
except IndexError:
    pass

print(MyString_1)
print(MyString_2)
print(MyString_3)
print(MyString_4)
print(MyString_5)
print(MyString_6)
print(MyString_7)
```

produce:

```
P
a
L
a
B
r
A

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ¿Se podría resumir un poco con:? for x in range(1,len(MyString)+1):
    exec(f"MyString_{x}={'MyString[x-1]'}")

Comment: @tincopasan. you didn't get it.